# Shouldn't mysql be using both indexes in a join?

Tags: mysql, index, join

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tx_in` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txid` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hashPrevOut` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` char(34) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hashPrevIndex` (`hashPrevOut`(8))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=641391046 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tx_out` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txid` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `btc_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` char(34) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `txidIndex` (`txid`(8))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=695391886 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And I am running the following query:

```
UPDATE tx_in LEFT JOIN tx_out ON tx_in.hashPrevOut = tx_out.txid SET 
tx_in.address = tx_out.address;
```

I modified it into a `SELECT` statement so that I could run `EXPLAIN` on it.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tx_in LEFT JOIN tx_out ON tx_in.hashPrevOut = tx_out.txid;
```

And got this output

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                          | rows      | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tx_in  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                         | 635293613 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tx_out | NULL       | ref  | txidIndex     | txidIndex | 9       | blockchain.tx_in.hashPrevOut |         2 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

But the execution plan doesn't have any reference to the index on `hashPrevOut`.  Should I be concerned about this?  It seems like it should just be using the two indexes to do the join.  As you can see the tables are quite large so this could make a big difference in execution time.

Comment: Seems like the problem with collations on the prefixed indexes. Try to move to the `BINARY` type instead of `CHAR`. `BINARY` is the string of byte-wise chars with no collations.

Comment: A) Do you really want to update **all** the 600M rows of the `tx_in` table?
B) Do you really want to use `LEFT JOIN` - and update rows that don't have a match with `tx_in.address = NULL`?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Please update the question with the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is due to the partial index. i.e. the index has only 8 char of `hashPrevOut`

It estimated that the number of matching first 8 char will lead to a second read from the table to compare the full value from first table with the full value in the other table, so the optimizer decided to skip the index, and deal with the table directly.

Comment: So what's the point of indexing then if the optimizer is just going to have to read the full string? I figured it would compare index to index and if it matches, its a match.  Is this not how it works?

Comment: It would be - if your query said to compare the first 8 chars in `tx_in.hashPrevOut` to the first 8 chars of `tx_out.txid`. Since that's not what the query says to compare, the indexes are of limited utility.

Comment: So in order to get proper use from the index I would need to join on LEFT(tx_in.hashPrevOut) = LEFT(tx_out.txid)?

Comment: "Prefix indexes" are virtually useless.  This is one example of why not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this suggestion,
A) in the query, tx_in.hashPrevOut = tx_out.txid
refers to two columns that are NOT indexed.
B) VARCHAR vs CHAR would conserve storage in the file (and HDD or SSD)
C) add INDEXES for the complete column content
for a predictable 1 to 1 match.
EXPLAIN SELECT original query to confirm your ndx's are working and ROWS should be much lower as well as time to complete.